# Receiving wrong file's group when using GetAccessControl().GetGroup()

Tags: c#, window, acl, fileinfo, group

I created a text file and removed all the groups except `SYSTEM` group.
When I am running the following code:

```
public static void CheckPermissions(string filePath)
{
    FileSecurity acl = new FileInfo(filePath).GetAccessControl();
    IdentityReference group = acl.GetGroup(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
}
```

It shows that my group is:

```
{S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-513}
```

Which [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab) is the group of `DOMAIN_USERS`.
But when I am looking through the GUI, it seems that it has only the `SYSTEM` group:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.getgroup?view=netframework-4.8#system-security-accesscontrol-objectsecurity-getgroup(system-type)), it because it gets the **primary group of the owner**, and not the group of the file:

> Gets the primary group associated with the specified owner.